# How to make source update while user types

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, inotifypropertychanged, propertychanged

This is a complete noob question that I am seemingly unable to figure out. I have a text box and a text block. The text box should be the deposit amount and the text block should be the balance after the deposit. It's basically just the value in the deposit box gets added to whatever value is in the new balance box, but I need this math to be done while the user types. Basically while the user types in the deposit text box I want the value in the deposit to be added to the value in the after deposit text block. This doesn't update and if I run it through the debugger it doesn't stop the program while the user types so I know it doesn't recognize that the property is being changed but I can't seem to wrap my head around why. I have the datacontext set and I know it is binded with no binding errors because the bindings work with regular text so i do not feel a need to show that here. I suspect this is just something simple with my math and the bindings.
The code for the textbox and text block are here:

```
 <!-- TextBlock and TextBox for deposit -->
    <TextBlock Text="Deposit:" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="30" FontWeight="Bold"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding DepositAmount, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="3" Padding="3" Margin="-60 15 30 10" Grid.Column="1"/>

    <!-- TextBlock and TextBox for new balance -->
    <TextBlock Text="New Balance:" Margin="5 0 0 0" TextAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="28" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding BalanceAfterDeposit, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" FontWeight="Bold" IsReadOnly="True" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="3" Padding="3" Margin="-60 15 30 10" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
```

The two properties are here:

```
public double DepositAmount
    {
        get => this._depositAmount;
        set
        {
            if (this._depositAmount != value)
            {
                this._depositAmount = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(DepositAmount));
            }
        }
    }

    public double BalanceAfterDeposit
    {
        get => this._balanceAfterDeposit + _balance;
        set
        {
            if ((this._balanceAfterDeposit + _balance) != value)
            {
                this._balanceAfterDeposit = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(BalanceAfterDeposit));
            }
        }
    }
```

This is probably a really dumb math mistake but any help will be appreciated! If you have any suggestions on my code that would really help too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how you are filling the _balanceAfterDeposit and _balance in your code. But based on the sample code given you can just provide `get` in BalanceAfterDeposit. Because you have made the `TextBox` `ReadyOnly` for new balance. So there is no way user is able to enter and therefore, only Get is enough.

```
    public double BalanceAfterDeposit
    {
        get => this._balanceAfterDeposit + _balance;
    }
```

Now, in order to show the updated BalanceAfterDeposit you need to call the `PropertyChanged` even on BalanceAfterDeposit whenever there is change in DepositAmount. So need to call it explicitly in set of DepositAmount Property.

```
        public double DepositAmount
    {
        get => this._depositAmount;
        set
        {
            if (this._depositAmount != value)
            {
                this._depositAmount = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(DepositAmount));
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(BalanceAfterDeposit));
            }
        }
    }
```

**Updated**:
By default Binding Mode is `TwoWay`, I have given `OneWay` Binding. This will resolve the markup runtime error.

```
 <TextBox Text="{Binding BalanceAfterDeposit, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=OneWay}" FontWeight="Bold" IsReadOnly="True" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="3" Padding="3" Margin="68,15,30,10" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
```

Let's give some value for _Balance amount.

```
private double _balance=19000;
```

and let's change the property Balance after Deposit

```
        public double BalanceAfterDeposit
    {
        get => this._depositAmount + _balance;
    }
```

I used _depositAmount  + _balance.

Comment: The text block still doesn't update and if I try to do just get on the balanceafterdeposit then it throws a system.windows.markup.xamlparseexception

Comment: Yep that fixes the error, but the UI doesn't update. If I type in the deposit amount the balance stays the same.

Comment: I have provide some amount in the _balance and used _depositAmount to display the change in Balance amount, since we don't know the other part of how the _balanceAfterDeposit is calculated from the sample code. This will clear your understanding

Comment: Yup I got it. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

As you are only editing data in DepositAmount, and BalanceAfterDeposit is only calculated field. (I assume you are doing some maths and after this, you want to display BalanceAfterDeposit. The only input required for BalanceAfterDeposit is DepositAmount in this example). 
Now problem happens here.

1. In DepositAmount you RaiseProperty changed only for DepositAmount. which does not notify other properties to do something. In your case you need to explicitly Raise Property for BalanceAfterDeposit. As given below

   public double DepositAmount
   {
       get => this._depositAmount;
       set
       {
           if (this._depositAmount != value)
           {
               this._depositAmount = value;
               OnPropertyChanged(nameof(DepositAmount));
               OnPropertyChanged(nameof(BalanceAfterDeposit));
           }
       }
   }

This will force UI to updated itself from BalanceAfterDeposit. Therefore you will see getter will be invoked.

2. As BalanceAfterDeposit is calculated field, and you are not going to updated it from outside (in your case.) so getter is enough for you i.e. do your calculation in getter, and return.
3. For improvement. I would like to suggest you to define async method, which will basically do all calculation and finally set value in  BalanceAfterDeposit. Call this method in setter of DepositAmount after setting value in private field. 
   In this suggestion, you have to define setter and getter in BalanceAfterDeposit.(As in point 2 i mentioned that you don't need setter).

Comment: The BalanceAfterDeposit property still won't update after I add the OnPropertyChanged of balanceafterdeposit into the depositamount setter

Comment: If you are just adding OnPropetyChange.It would not update. because it will get value from BalanceAfterDeposit . where your implementation is this._balanceAfterDeposit + _balance. where in your implementation there is no way to set anyvalue to _balanceAfterDeposit.

So You need to properly set value to _balanceAfterDeposit. i.e.
 public double BalanceAfterDeposit
        {
            get
            {
               return this._depositAmount + _balance;
            }           
        }